# non-null rows of the row space of a RREF matrix are linearly idependent.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm trying to prove that, given a RREF matrix $B$ with components in $\mathbb{R}$, if you take its row space, all the non-null rows are linearly independent vectors. I have this:

Let $B$ be a RREF matrix. We can assume that, for each non-null row, we have:

\begin{align*}
    v_{1} &= \begin{pmatrix} \alpha_{11} & \alpha_{12} & ... & \alpha_{1n} \end{pmatrix}\\
    v_{2} &= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \alpha_{22} & ... & \alpha_{2n} \end{pmatrix}\\
    v_{3} &= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & ... & \alpha_{3n} \end{pmatrix}\\
        &.\\
        &.\\
        &.\\
    v_{m} &= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & ... & \alpha_{mm} & \alpha_{m(m+1)} & ... & \alpha_{mn} \end{pmatrix}\\    
\end{align*}

with $v_{i}$ being the vector given by the i-th row.

But I don't really know how to prove that any vector $v_{i}$ can't be a linear combination from all the others. I know I can prove that any given vector $v_{i}$ can't be generated by the vectors below it, but I don't know how to prove it can be generated by those beneath it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the coefficients $c_1,\dots,c_n$ be such that $c_1v_1 + \cdots + c_n v_n = 0$. Let $j$ be the smallest index $i$ for which $c_i \neq 0$. We can then rewrite
$$
c_1v_1 + \cdots + c_n v_n = 0 \implies v_j = - \frac{c_{j+1}}{c_j}v_{j+1} - \cdots - \frac{c_n}{c_j} v_n.
$$
However, as you say in your post, this is impossible.

Comment: I don't think I completely get it, but thanks, I think I can go from here.

Comment: Sorry, but how can I assure that, in case there's no $c_{i} = 0$, $v_j$ can't be generated by a linear combination of those before it?

Comment: @RaulPeña If every $c_i$ is non-zero, then the rearrangement I suggest tells you that $v_1$ is a linear combination of those after it, which is impossible

Comment: Thank you very much.